# ets match_object with match spec

Tags: erlang, ets

```
 -record(rule, {id, low, high}).


 test_ets() ->
    ets:new(rule_table,[named_table,public,bag]),
    ets:insert(rule_table, #rule{id=1, low=2, high=5}),
    ets:match_object(rule_table, [{'$1',[{'>=', {element, #rule.low, '$1'}, 2}, 
            {'=<', {element, #rule.high, '$1'}, 5} 
            ], ['$_']}]).
```

This function only get an empty list while I want to pick this record with low =< X =< high.

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wrong, use ets:select instead.

But how is the performance using matchSpec? Is it all table scan?

Comment: Yes, the entire table will be scanned for matching data. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html for more info.